# I cant make this query more efficient

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Im trying to create a script that shows the most viewed documents, but it's creating many temporary tables on disk....
Here's the query, I don't see where the error is or where the query turns abusive.

```
select 
notas.notid,
notas.ttl,
notas.brv,
notas.fch,
nots.notid,
nots.cnt,
nots.fch,
nots.sccn,
SUM(nots.hit) AS lasuma
FROM cadenano_cbc_noticias.notas
INNER JOIN cadenano_cbc_relacbc.nots
ON notas.notid = nots.notid
WHERE nots.cnt = 'notas'
AND nots.fch BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY nots.notid
ORDER BY lasuma DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show your table definitions. Optimizing queries is often related to indexes.

Comment: Please post a explain SELECT also. Do you have index on the nots.fch=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up a query if you look at the part of the query that uses the data for calculations: `where` clauses and `order` clauses mostly.

If you don't have already then add indexes on `nots.cnt` and `nots.fch`.

It is also a good practice to run a `explain`:

```
explain select notas.notid, ...
```

The output will tell you if keys are used and where not.

Comment: I executed an EXPLAIN SELECT on all columns and this is what came out

These are the ones with index.

notas.notid,
notas.fch

These are not indexed

notas.ttl,
notas.brv,

nots.notid,
nots.cnt,
nots.fch,
nots.sccn,
nots.hit

I executed an EXPLAIN SELECT on all columns and this is what came out.

These are the ones indexed.

notas.notid,
notas.fch.

These are not indexed...

nnotas.ttl,
nnotas.brv,
nnots.notid,
nnots.cnt,
nnots.fch,
nnots.sccn,
nots.hit

So for what I can see and understand I must index:  nots.cnt  and nots.hit

Am I correct?